# Rails - Nested loop not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-loops

Each subject has many pages and each page has many versions. On the show subject page for the owner of that subject, I want the user to be able to update all the pages and versions on that page. However, I get this error:

```
undefined method `versions' for nil:NilClass
```

My show page:

```
%h1
  = @subject.title
%h3 Subject Synopsis
%p
  = @subject.synopsis

- @subject.pages.each do |p|
    %h6
      = p.number
      = ": " + p.title
    %p
      = p.synopsis
    %table
      %tbody
        - p.versions.each do |v|
          %tr
           %td v.number
           %td v.create_at
    = render 'versions/form'
```

Versions form:

```
= simple_form_for [@page, @page.versions.build] do |f|
  = f.input :number, placeholder: 'Number', label: false
  = f.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Content', label: false
  = f.button :submit
```

Comment: can you post controller too?

Comment: Done. I think it's all wrong...

Comment: where is your show page action in your controller?

Comment: I am not able to see show action in your pages controller

Comment: There is none for pages because the pages don't contain the content

Comment: I have updated with a screenshot. Actually, I want the page show to pull the latest version and display that. I haven't gotten that far yet though...

Comment: There is no show action in your pages_controller.rb. Please post the entire controller and the URL you are calling.

Comment: That is the entire controller. I'm not sure what the show action has to do with anything at this point. Can you explain why I need it for solving my current problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't passing through the loop variable. Answer is:

```
= render 'versions/form', p: p


= simple_form_for [p, p.versions.build] do |f|
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- @subject.pages.each do |p|
        %h6
          = p.number
          = ": " + p.title
        %p
          = p.synopsis
        %table
          %tbody
            - p.versions.each do |v|
```

Comment: what is the difference between your code and the code which is pasted in question?

Comment: the question has been updated since i posted this answer